# Texture for 3D models are transparent at places

Tags: texturing, uv, edit-mode, import

I am using **Blender 2.83** as a part of my Masters project. I have obtained 3D models of various fishes (.obj files), and I import them using

File > Import > Wavefront (.obj)

The models loads without errors, but the textures are "corrupted". I would appreciate any help and/or pointers on how to fix this. You can see images below. The "dark spots" are transparent spots

[image: "Corrupted" textures]

Some (maybe all) of the models are obtained from sketchfab, which have 3D previews where the textures look correct. The fish "groups" are the models viewed from left and right.

Beneath you can see a closer look of a model as well as the UV-editor view in case that is relevant.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe pack your images and share one of your fishes so that we can take a look: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hello :). If this only happens in Eevee, you need to change the material blend mode (perhaps to opaque).

Comment: @JachymMichal Thank you very very much, that fixed it! 

If you post as an answer I can check your answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by your material's blend mode.
You have 2 options:

1. In Material settings uncheck *Show Backface*

or

2. Change Blend mode to *Opaque* (this will fully disable transparency)

[image]